# Disable/hide magnifier loupe

Tags: ios, pspdfkit

I am using an older version of PSPDFKit, 3.7.0, and I need to disable the loupe that shows up at long tap on a document but keep the other menu items. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Charlie,

PSPDFKit Founder here. You really should update our PDF SDK - we've improved A LOT since 3.7, it's also quite dangerous to modify the framework without having any tests.

So we usually only support people with ongoing subscriptions, but this one here is a freebie, though no guarantees that things work similar in 3.7, I'm looking at the codebase for 6.6pre here.

Look for `PSPDFLoupeView`, that's the class that is the loupe. `PSPDFTextSelectionView` (might just be called a bit different in v3) controls the logic to present the loupe. Check if there's something like `- (void)showLoupe:(PSPDFLoupeView *)loupe animated:(BOOL)animated` there and override it.

This definitely works in v6, can't say if this works in v3 but maybe it helps. And if you're interested in getting a new license, ping us at https://pspdfkit.com/sales/.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, in the meantime we've upgraded the framework. I have another question though, the UIMenuController for editing annotations only appears when I long tap on the document. Is there a property that I need to set? The shouldShowMenuItems is being called and the array is not nill but nothing happens afterwards.

Comment: That seems like some of your custom code breaks our logic. Send us a runnable sample in source code form to our support page and we'll have a look. (zip via Dropbox works best for large samples)